# Add autoincrement to an already populated DT--Updating the values

Tags: c#, datatable, datacolumn

I have a DataTable I'm reading from a csv file. I need to add an ID AUTOINCREMENT column to the DT AFTER it's read from the file (I'm using a CSV parser so I don't have to readLine, i.e. the data is loaded to the DT for me)

I'm adding the DataColumn with the autoincrementseed and autoincrementstep values OK.

My question is: How do I have the DT assign IDs (populate the DataColumn) with values for the rows ALREADY PRESENT in the DT? I don't care about matching the contents of the rows with specific numbers, I just want to have a predictable & explicit row id.

Notice that I'm not using a DB to back this DataTable. I'm just taking advantage of my CSV parser's ability to read a file from disk, parse it and return a new DataTable.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# DataTable:" and such. That's what the titles are for.

Answer (score 0):

Add the column, loop thru the data and set the id, then add the autoinc and set the seed to dataset.rows.count.

Which is pretty much the way you'd do the same thing in sql table.